# Button with HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I want the javascript to link the data from the url, but this is not working.

I tried the following code:

```
    <script language="javascript">
    <span class="buttonAction"><a href="checkout_shipping.php?info=document.writeln(document.location);">
     <img src="images/checkout.png" width="93">
     </a></script>
```

can anyone help me with this ? many thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do a little bit better. The example code is extremely wrong and it's hard to figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'd suggest starting with [a basic JavaScript tutorial](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Web_Standards_Curriculum#JavaScript_core_skills).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put html in a script tag. Some pointers: Put the html above the script, give the a tag an id and use javascript to set the href attribute from the script part.

```
<span class="buttonAction">
  <a id="thelink" href="">
    <img src="images/checkout.png" width="93">
  </a>
</span>
<script language="javascript">
// insert javascript code to set the href attribute here (read a javascript tutorial)
</script>
```

see: http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp, http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp

(this solution is the closest to your original code, later you might prefer to move your javascript elsewhere and/or start using javascript framework)

Comment: A better source of information is the MDN JavaScript Guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide

Answer (score 0):

You can't put html in a javascript tag. If you want to print the link you can do it like this:

```
<script language="javascript">
    document.write('<span class="buttonAction"><a href="checkout_shipping.php?info='+encodeURIComponent(document.location)+'"><img src="images/checkout.png" width="93" alt=""/></a><span>');
</script>
```

Comment: Why is `document.write` needed here? Why not simply remove the `script` tag?

Comment: To add `encodeURIComponent(document.location)` to the link. You have to scroll to see it.